# is there any API for changing the credit card number of RecurringPaymentsProfile?

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented the Paypal recurring payment profile using the API found on this link,

[Link for RecurringPayments API](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/RecurringPayments/)

This link also contains the form for `UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` , but am not getting how will i process all the parameters which i got from this form... for updating the Recurring Payment Profile.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your asking, could you clarify.  This API would be used to update the profile, such as credit card number, terms etc.

Comment: Thanks @PP_MTS_Chad  for reply...
Yes you rare right...exactly am asking that, is there any API for changing the credit card number of **RecurringPaymentsProfile**. What i got API is present in that link, but there is only an HTML form for filling up the information(to update the recursive transaction) but not having any processing 'PHP' code for that form...

Comment: You can update the credit/billing details.  See page 160 of the developers guide.  https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_nvpapi_developerguide.pdf

Comment: Hey @PP_MTS_Chad... thanks, Now i have set all the variables from that **pdf** and made a call as....   `$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();` `$createRPProfileResponse = $paypalService->UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile($UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReqObj);`    
Where **$UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReqObj** contains all the details.  But am not getting any response from paypal. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check your error logs on your system to see if anything is erroring out, and make sure that you are not blocking the communication.